# IOException java audio

Tags: java, audio, audio-streaming, ioexception

My program keeps giving me an IOException error, when I run it, and I cannot figure out why or how to fix it.

I imported

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import sun.audio.*;
```

I have theses instance variables:
private FileInputStream in;
private AudioStream as;

In my constructor I have this code:

```
try {
   in = new FileInputStream("Music.mp3");
}
catch(IOException e) {System.out.println("Error1");} 
try{
   as = new AudioStream(in);
}
catch(IOException e) {System.out.println("Error3");}
```

When I run the file I keep getting Error3
If anyone knows how to fix this i would greatly appreciate it
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to test if the file exists?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Well I have the file on my computer in the same directory as the code.  Is that not what you mean?  If not, how do i test that?

I'm a total beginner, sorry.  How do I find the stack trace?

Comment: There isn't going to be much of a stack trace with the code as written. OP, consider doing `e.printStackTrace();` rather than `System.out.println("Error3");`

Comment: @Hello: if it's in the same directory as the code, your program might be looking in the correct place for it. To see where Java is looking have something like `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));` in your program before the error occurs.  Note that my code snippet was not tested.

Comment: it gives me java.io.IOException: could not create audio stream from input stream

Comment: It gave me the correct directory

Comment: Just in case, try to specify full path. Like `c:\tmp\music.mp3`

Comment: C:\Users\user\Desktop\homework\compsci

its looking for music.mp3, was that supposed to show up in the path?

Comment: I mean try `in = new FileInputStream("C:\Users\user\Desktop\homework\compsci\Music.mp3")` to completely exclude paths stuff from the equation

Comment: Also, do `System.out.println("Error3" + e.getMessage())` to get more info about error

Comment: `import sun.audio.*;`  If you are dipping into Sun proprietary classes just to play a sound, you are doing it wrong.  Check out the (newly created) [javasound info tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for code that uses a `Clip`.  There are other methods that can be used when a `Clip` won't cut it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try another input stream like:

```
try {
        audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope it may help.